# How to start service mysql from cmd without knowing the name of the service?

Tags: mysql, windows-services, cmd

I need to check if `mysqld` service is running. However, the name of the service may be different depending on the computer it is installed on.  For example, on one computer it might be named `MySQL56`.  So I use `net start mysql56` instead.

How can I get the name of the service ahead of time?

I tried something like `C:\>"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld" --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini"` In cmd, here I can change path to user defined during installation or on first launch and it will start that service.

However, if I execute that then the cmd window stays open waiting for the service to stop.  Which means the user has to manually close the window.  Is there a way to execute the line above and have the cmd window automatically close itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not quite clear to me what you're trying to achieve. Do you want to find out the name of an installed MySQL service? You can use `wmic` for that:

```
wmic service where "PathName LIKE '%mysqld%'" get DisplayName /value | findstr /i "displayname"
if %errorlevel% equ 0 (
  echo MySQL service installed.
) else (
  echo MySQL service not installed.
)
```

Or do you want to start `mysqld` without installing a service? You can do that with the `--standalone` option.

```
set SERVER=%ProgramFiles%\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld
set CONFIG=%ProgramData%\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini
"%SERVER%" --defaults-file="%CONFIG%" --standalone
```

The process is always blocking the console, though, so if you want the script to do other stuff while `mysqld` is running in the background you need to start it in another `cmd` instance:

```
set SERVER=%ProgramFiles%\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld
set CONFIG=%ProgramData%\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini
start "" "%COMSPEC%" /c "%SERVER%" --defaults-file="%CONFIG%" --standalone
```

Add the option `/b` to suppress the second command prompt window:

```
start "" /b "%COMSPEC%" /c "%SERVER%" --defaults-file="%CONFIG%" --standalone
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, the idea was to check if the mysqld is running, if not, run it, because its needed for my application. That's why I was trying to shutdown console after starting service, user don't need it. That wmic is perfect, I can store name of it and then use that net start thing, so thank you very much.